# Can i breathe pure oxygen gas?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Sorry for the irrelevant tag because I was unable to find An appropriate one .Suppose there is a vaccum chamber and i filled completely with O2 without any traces of any other gases . Can a normal person breathe in it comfortably. I suspect it as pure O2 may act as oxidiser but since we need it for breathing . Can our organs manage that.

Comment: Can you? Yes. Comfortably? No, to the point that you'd probably get [oxygen poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity) and die. Then again, pressure is important.

Comment: Like everything in chemistry, the amount and the proportions are very important, it is often the difference between the poison and the antidote. Too much of anything is usually bad. It is true that you can drink water but if you drink too much it could drop your body pressure and be harmful for you. So yes, you can breathe, the real question is for how long?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen#Toxicity, last paragraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breathing pure oxygen is potentially toxic. At reduced pressures, pure oxygen can be inhaled for days, or weeks. It is used to treat individuals suffering from stroke, heart attack, etc. and can be comfortably used for up to 24 hours. The body can be overwhelmed by oxygen during long periods or higher pressures, free radicals in the oxygen cause damage through oxidative stress which can result in tissue damage and death.